# Grabbing the key of a value using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to grasp some basic concepts by building a project.  I have the following div that will calculate a value from a key selected in a dropdown (clearly the original data store is an object!).

as you can see below all the work I am doing in my controller is with the value, and I'm displaying the key.  in my controller, how would I have access to that key {{k}}, (keeping in mind I want the key of the one that is selected)? I want to do something with that key in my controller.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="calc()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v" >{{k}}</option>
    </select>
```

In my controller I have the calculate function, which grabs the value:

```
$scope.calc = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
        if($scope.selectedItem2){
                $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `getKey` function for this purpose:

```
function getKey(obj, value) 
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] === value) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Modify your `calc` function:

```
$scope.calc = function() {
    $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
    if($scope.selectedItem2){
            $scope.calculatedValue1 = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);
    }
    $scope.key1 = getKey($scope.data.playerInfo, $scope.calculatedValue1);
}
```

This would finally fetch the value in `$scope.key1` variable.